# Bad placement on the page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

My file:    `/app/views/pins/index.html.erb`

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
<%= image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %><br/>
<%= pin.description %><br/>
<%= link_to 'show', pin %><br/>
<% if pin.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %><br/>
<%= link_to 'delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'are you sure?' }%><br/>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to 'New pin', new_pin_path %>
```

I don't know why my page look good only with 1 pin , when i add 2nd pin on the website, all of image look bad - like on this screen:

[image: screen]

[image: right click]

Comment: yeah, hard to say what exactly is wrong there. Right click on that misplaced pin, choose "inspect element" and enter the wonderful world of debugging page markup :)

Comment: Everything looks good in my opinion, I edited the post and paste what is hidden there

Comment: Totally depends on your CSS.

Comment: This is my first site with book, I do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Put a **br** tag after first <% end %>.

Comment: What would that accomplish? Given the code that we see, a `<br/>` _should_ be there, after delete button

Answer (score 1):

Anchor elements (i.e. the `<a href="...">` tags) are not block elements by default, so what you're seeing is the "delete" anchor tag and the second anchor tag (containing the image) rendering on the same line.

Move the `<br>` tag from the bottom of your code to inside your `each` loop (under the "delete" link), and it should look right.

---

Sidenote: it might not be a bad idea to get rid of those `<br>` elements, and wrap things up inside `<div>` elements instead, which are block elements. It gives your code a nicer structure, and makes it easier to style the spacing with CSS.

Comment: But, according to code posted, each link _should_ be followed with `<br/>`. Where did they go? Does the OP show the wrong code?

Comment: Hmm, good spot. I'm drawing this conclusion from the screenshot of the rendered code... and it doesn't match the view code provided.